# Math Proof Help

Tags: proof-writing

So I am supposed to add some condition to the original proposition to make it true but I do not know what condition I need to add.

Original Proposition: If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and $xy>0$, then:
$$(x+y)/2≥√xy$$

Proof: Let us assume the hypothesis to be true. Adding some condition to the original proposition we get:
$x-y≥0$

By algebra we get:
$$x-y≥0$$
$$(x-y)^2≥0$$
$$x^2-2xy+y^2≥0$$
$$x^2+2xy+y^2≥4xy$$
$$(x+y)^2≥4xy$$
$$x+y≥2√xy$$
$$(x+y)/2≥√xy$$

I thought that I needed to add the condition that $x≥y$ but this isn't the case because let's say the $x=-1$ and $y=-1$ it would be false. I then thought that $x$ and $y$ need to be positive integers but then I don't know how to use that to get $x-y≥0$

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need that $x-y \geq 0$, as $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$ no matter the value of $x-y$.  What you *do* need is that $x+y \geq 0$, as when you take the square root in the second to last step you need to know that $x+y$ is the positive one (and not $-(x+y)$).

When $xy > 0$ this is equivalent to $x,y \geq 0$.

Comment: So from the fact that $x≥0$ and $y≥0$ you get that $x+y≥0$ thus I can use that in second to last step to take the square root is what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

One: (both $x,y$ must be positive)

Notice $$( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 = x - 2 \sqrt{xy} + y \geq 0 \implies \frac{x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy} $$

Another solution follows from young inequality: If $x,y$ are positive and $m +n  = 1 $, then

$$ x^my^n \leq xm + yn $$

Now, if we put $m = n = \frac{1}{2} $, then

$$ x^{1/2}y^{1/2} = \sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2} = \frac{x + y}{2}$$